# rewrite rules not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use some rewrite rules inside the Apache virtual hosts configuration httpd-vhosts.conf and it works fine there. Because I want to move to a managed server I have to use the .htaccess file because I don't have access to the apache configuration files.

I tried it locally and somehow I don't get this working at all.
Locally I use xampp 1.8.3 (Apache 2.4.10). I put the .htaccess file in the root directory of the virtual host and use this lines for testing

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /testrule /about/about.php [L]
```

I always get an 404 error when calling `localhost/testrule`
It works fine when I put it in the `httpd-vhosts.conf`. 
**mod_rewrite** is enabled and I have set `AllowOverride All` in the Directory part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can quick check the htaccess rewrite rules here:
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ or here:
http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Just get rid of the leading slash in the RewriteRule and you are done

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule testrule /about/about.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://tltech.com/info/rewriterule-in-htaccess-vs-httpd-conf/) clearly mention

> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against
>   the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query
>   string (e.g. “/app1/index.html”).
>
> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be
>   matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that
>   led the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. “app1/index.html” or
>   “index.html” depending on where the directives are defined).

So in virtual host context, matches start from `/testrule/...`

While in `.htaccess` and `<Directory/>` context, it matches `testrule/...`

Comment: Thanks for this information, now I understand the background why I have to remove the leading slash

Comment: @RahilWazir I always imagined it could be like this, but never bothered to search for it. Thanks for that info.